# Thread callback is not calling. why?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, interface

Ok, Let me simplify the scenario first

Actually I want to trigger some action after completing a background thread operations.

Hence I made a thread callback interface like below.

interface ***OnThreadCompleted.java***

```
package xml.parser;

public interface OnThreadCompleted {

    public void OnThreadCompleted();

}
```

and here is my actual **XMLParserThread.java** extending the Threads

```
public class XMLParserThread extends Thread {

ArrayList<Integer> listWeatherCode;
ArrayList<String> listWeatherDesc;
ArrayList<String> listIcon_day;
ArrayList<String> listIcon_night;

Context context;
String fileName;
XMLParser xmlParser;

OnThreadCompleted listner;

public XMLParserThread(Context context, String fileName,
        OnThreadCompleted listner) {

    this.context = context;
    this.fileName = fileName;
    this.listner = listner;
}

@Override
public void run() {

    xmlParser = new XMLParser();

    listWeatherCode = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    listWeatherDesc = new ArrayList<String>();
    listIcon_day = new ArrayList<String>();
    listIcon_night = new ArrayList<String>();

    String xmlResponse = null;
    try {
        xmlResponse = xmlParser.getXmlFromFile(context, fileName);
        Document doc = xmlParser.getDomElement(xmlResponse);
        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("condition");

        for (int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++) {

            Element element = (Element) nList.item(i);

            listWeatherCode.add(Integer.valueOf(xmlParser.getValue(element,
                    "code")));
            listWeatherDesc.add(xmlParser.getValue(element, "description"));
            listIcon_day.add(xmlParser.getValue(element, "day_icon"));
            listIcon_night.add(xmlParser.getValue(element, "night_icon"));
        }

        Log.e("listWeatherCode", listWeatherCode.toString());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    super.run();
}
}
```

and Im calling my thread in my activity like

```
private void callXMLParserThread() {

    String fileName = "weather_conditions.xml";
    parserThread = new XMLParserThread(context, fileName,
            new OnThreadCompleted() {

                @Override
                public void OnThreadCompleted() {

                    Log.e("parserThread State", parserThread.getState()
                            + ""); // **Label 2**
                }

            });

    parserThread.start();

    Log.e("parserThread State", parserThread.getState()
            + ""); // **Label 1**

}
```

***Experiments:***
I have check the log mentioned in Label 1 is returning me the state of Thread as `WAITING`. also I have checked my thread is also performing its all operations,

***Problem***

Its not calling my callback Method in my activity, Hence the Log in my activity returning nothing, as mention in Label 2

Please Guide me where I m wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just a sidenote: You know about [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), do you?

Comment: Yes I know, don't need to discuss it right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is that, even though you have taken `listener` as parameter is thread, you are **not invoking** the listener's callback method from thread

```
OnThreadCompleted listner;

public XMLParserThread(Context context, String fileName,
        OnThreadCompleted listner) {

    this.context = context;
    this.fileName = fileName;
    this.listner = listner;
}

@Override
public void run() {
   //listener.OnThreadCompleted() call is missing
}
```

Secondly, its [highly recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541487/implements-runnable-vs-extends-thread) to use `Runnable` interface instead of extending `Thread` class, unless you really have a strong reason

Also, if you are expecting some value back from thread, use `Callable` and `Future` objects provided by `ExecutorService` class. [More details here.](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/get_netbeans_6)

Comment: OMG, my code was not wrong, just the one line :) Thanks for the description also, How can I use this code in a runnable interface and what are the strong reasons for using the runnable interface not extending the thread class.

Comment: Now the callback method is calling perfectly but, the Log always returning me the state of thread as RUNNABLE. when it will return me the completed or finished etc?